# How to write data to Excel in webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, sharepoint-2013

I am able to read data from SharePoint excel using below link

https://medium.com/@guiltabasa/how-to-read-excel-file-from-sharepoint-document-library-net-c-889374826d99

I am able to store it in some object.

Now my requirement is to add some data to excel columns which is in above object and I want to download it to local.

How to do that.

Any references are much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659069/writing-data-to-an-existing-excel-file-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing Data to an Existing Excel File in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659069/writing-data-to-an-existing-excel-file-in-c-sharp)